Too many open files with Azure AI Services Document Intelligence Read 3.0 container
Some app deployed on our K8s cluster uses the mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cognitive-servies/form-recognizer/read-3.0:2022-08-31 container.
We see increasing open files in /tmp. The lsof utility shows many /tmp/tmp<randomString> (deleted). Yesterday there were 13'000. Today already 16'000 on a single k8s pod.  Totally there are 4 and 10'000 open files more than yesterday. Pods are running for 5 days.
restarting the container obviously resolves the issue until it gets too many again. we're considering to do a daily restart of the pods.
IMHO the app should just properly close these filehandles!?
